# What kind of character is &Mac198;

Tags: html

Found this on a web page and I'm wondering what the writer wanted to write?

&Mac198;

// Anders

Comment: [This](http://www.wildisle.ca/islandalpine/updates.html) web page uses it in `ar&Mac198;te` to form [Arête](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arête). Looks more like a character set issue to me, though.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly:

```
>>> print '\xc6'.decode('macroman')
∆
```

Comment: [This web page](http://www.mu6.com/einstein.html) and the linked PDF seems to support this.